# How to translate variable containing html with the i18n_variable module?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am trying to translate a variable with i18n_variable module. I am using the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_variable_info().
 */
function MY_MODULE_variable_info($options) {
  $variables['pm_email_notify_subject'] = array(
    'title' => t('My variable title'),
    'description' => t('The description', array(), $options),
    'default' => t('A good default value', array(), $options),
    'type' => 'string',
    'localize' => TRUE,
    'access' => 'administer checkout',    
    'group' => 'my_variable_group',
  );
  return $variables;
}
```

This works as expected: I can choose the variable to be translated at `/admin/config/regional/i18n/variable` and when I do so, I can find its value via `/admin/config/regional/translate`.

But the problem is, that the variable contains HTML markup and although this works with the original content, the markup in the translated string gets converted to HTML entities. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is, not to use the interface for string translation of the [i18n module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) under `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`, but instead go to the admin path, where the original (not translated) variable is set. In my use case this was `/admin/config/messaging/privatemsg`. [As I patched](https://www.drupal.org/node/2295125) the [privatemsg module,](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) to make it's variables translatable, on the module's admin form appeared a language selection option:

[image: Translate variables via admin interface]

If you put in the translation there, all HTML is preserved. I guess this would be the general approach to translate variables, which are set via the admin interface. If you have to translate a variable, which is not set via the admin interface, I guess you have to provide the translation in code.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I used when I faced a similar problem in a different context is to preventively replace tag-markers by the corresponding entity in the content before it is processed.

Adapated to your case, it might look like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_variable_info().
 */
function MY_MODULE_variable_info($options) {
  $my_variable_content = preg_replace_all(
    '/<([^>]*)>/', '&lt;$1&gt;',
    'A good default value with some <tags> inside'
  );
  $variables['pm_email_notify_subject'] = array(
    'title' => t('My variable title'),
    'description' => t('The description', array(), $options),
    'default' => t($my_variable_content, array(), $options),
    'type' => 'string',
    'localize' => TRUE,
    'access' => 'administer checkout',    
    'group' => 'my_variable_group',
  );
  return $variables;
}
```

This way, the finally rendered text keeps its "<" and ">" intacts.

But caution: it might be not appropriate to your case, so try it carefully.

Comment: You can't put variable content into the t-function.

Comment: @user5950. Sorry, you're right! I read your question too fast, so I focused to the "A good default value" as if it was the content where you wanted to allow tags. Then I felt in a second error: even in that case, my solution was wrong and should have been `'default' => t(@var, array(var => $my_variable_content), $options)`, which becomes absurd!